# How to find out new dimensions of textarea upon resize (PHP)

Tags: php, resize, textarea

I have a textarea element on my page that can be resized in various brovsers. I would like to find out new dimensions (cols and rows) after resize, so that, when the page is reloaded, i can update cols and rows properties inside php script. This way textarea element dimensions would remain the way user has set them.

Is there a way to accomplish this without js, and how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not without javascript, no. Javascript is about the only client executing code that can look at this sort of data and do anything with it. PHP doesn't care about anything after it has completed executing the code and sent all the data to the user, so that's out. I haven't tried silverlight, but I doubt that there is anything in it that could give back property elements in it. You are left with javascript.

Comment: I suspected as much, but needed some confirmation, since I'm new to all this. Thanks.

Comment: @Bruce Sorry mate, sometimes the answer you get is what you expect, but not what you want.